# BigQuery GroupBy with STRUCT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I can successfully run the following query using standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
  city,
  DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR) AS start
FROM 
  sandbox.CountByCity
GROUP BY 
    city, start
```

But it fails when I nest the `start` value in a STRUCT, like this...

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
  city,
  STRUCT(
    DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR) AS start
  ) as timeSpan
FROM 
  sandbox.CountByCity
GROUP BY 
    city, timeSpan.start
```

In this case, I get the following error message:

> Cannot GROUP BY field references from SELECT list alias timeSpan at [10:11]

What is the correct way to write the query so that the `start` value is nested within a STRUCT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using `ANY_VALUE`. The struct value that you get is well-defined, since the value is the same for the entire group:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
  city,
  ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(
    DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR) AS start
  )) as timeSpan
FROM 
  sandbox.CountByCity
GROUP BY 
    city, DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR);
```

Here is an example using some sample data:

```
WITH `sandbox.CountByCity` AS (
  SELECT 'Seattle' AS city, STRUCT(DATE '2017-12-11' AS intervalStart) AS timeInterval UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Seattle', STRUCT(DATE '2016-11-10' AS intervalStart) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Seattle', STRUCT(DATE '2017-03-24' AS intervalStart) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kirkland', STRUCT(DATE '2017-02-01' AS intervalStart)
)
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
  city,
  ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(
    DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR) AS start
  )) as timeSpan
FROM 
  `sandbox.CountByCity`
GROUP BY 
    city, DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR);
```

You could also consider [submitting a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) to enable `GROUP BY` with `STRUCT` types.

Comment: For future folks, please add a +1 to this feature request so we can improve this experience. https://issuetracker.google.com/181880172

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why exactly you would wanted this - but believe it is for some reason - so try below (at least formally it does what you ask)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  totalCount, 
  city, 
  STRUCT(start) timeSpan
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
    city,
    DATE_TRUNC(timeInterval.intervalStart, YEAR) AS start
  FROM `sandbox.CountByCity`
  GROUP BY city, start
)
```